# Tab Title shown as External Page in Console

Tags: apex, visualforce, service-cloud-console

I have created Visual force page on my custom object and add a custom button to it and when the user clicks on the custom button (opening VFP)

the page is opened in New tab, but the Tab title is set as `External Page`.

How can I change and add `custom_object__c.Name` in the title ?

Answer (score 1):

i able to found the solution finally: [source](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205552&language=en_US#attachments)

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/20.0/integration.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testSetTabTitle() {
            //Set the current tab's title
            sforce.console.setTabTitle('Lead: {!Lead.Name}');
        }
        var pageLoad = window.onload;
          window.onload = function() {
                if (pageLoad) {
                        pageLoad();
                }
                  testSetTabTitle();
          }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Does your VF page have its `title` attribute set on the `<apex:page>` tag?</strike>

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" title="{!CustomObject__c.Name}" >
```

Related [`<apex:page >` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)

---

**Update**

Looks like you've got to do this with the Console Integration Toolkit in your VF page markup.

```
//Sets the title of the current tab to "SFDC"
function setTitle() {
    sforce.console.setTabTitle('SFDC');
}
```

Documentation: [Sample Visualforce Page Using the Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_sample_vf.htm)

Comment: still get the `External Page` but remember my app is a service cloud console

Comment: opens the vf page in tab within the console app

Comment: @NickKahn corrected/updated the answer.